# Using word boundaries

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to know if there is some sort of rule to use word boundaries, besides using in words. In my case i want capture a value after a specific word, should i wrap the word with \b's?

```
/\bCOMP:\s*(\d{2}\/\d{4})\b/
```

vs:

```
/\bCOMP\b:\s*\b(\d{2}\/\d{4})\b/
```

What is the more correct way?

Also, will \b affect the performance??

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you don't need `\b` unless you want to avoid words containing the string.

- `\bCOMP:` is useful, because it avoids matching `SOMECOMP:` if you only want `COMP`.
- `/COMP\b:` is unnecessary, because the `:` already ensures that `COMP` will end at a word boundary. Similarly, `:\s*\b\d{2}` is unnecessary, because it already requires that the characters before `\d{2}` are non-word characters.

The real performance difference is likely to be very small, if it exists at all. However, omitting unnecessary `\b` patterns makes the regex simpler and more legible.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks @nrabinowitz